# Why do I get the error message Object has no method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code however am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<addThis> has no method 'returnValue' (anonymous function)`

```
function addThis() {
    this.value1 = 1;
    this.value2 = 2;

    var returnValue = function () {
        return (this.value1 + this.value2);
    }
}

//Instantiate object and write response
var simpleObject = new addThis();
document.write(simpleObject.returnValue());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `returnValue` is just a local variable in the `addThis` function, it doesn't end up in the object that is created.

Assign the function to a property of the object:

```
function addThis() {
  this.value1 = 1;
  this.value2 = 2;

  this.returnValue = function() {
    return this.value1 + this.value2;
  };
}
```

Or use the prototype for the object:

```
function addThis() {
  this.value1 = 1;
  this.value2 = 2;
}

addThis.prototype.returnValue = function() {
  return this.value1 + this.value2;
};
```

Comment: Do I have to specify the `this` keyword when assigning `returnValue` as a property of the `addThis` object? Can I not just have `returnValue = ....`? If no, why is that?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Yes, you always have to specify the object when accessing the properties, either using `this.propertyName` or `someVariable.propertyName`. The scope is never *inside* the object like in an object oriented language. If you use `var returnValue = ...` it is a local variable, and if you use just `returnValue = ...` then it becomes a global variable (unless you have `var returnValue;` anywhere else in the function).

Answer (score 1):

when you use `this.` it is *public* in scope. when you use `var`, it is *private*. since you used `var returnValue`, it is private, and thus not exposed for use.

In fact, i'm guessing you wanted to hide the values and expose the getter, so reverse what you did..

```
function addThis() {
    var value1 = 1;
    var value2 = 2;

    this.returnValue = function () {
        return (this.value1 + this.value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "In fact, i'm guessing you wanted to hide the values and expose the getter, so reverse what you did..". Sorry am new to the world of Javascript so want to make sure that I understand what you mean.

Comment: Does `public scope` also mean `global scope`? I thought `this` was limited to the object in question as opposed to being in the public scope?.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey no, global means your variable is actually within the window namespace. so instead of writing var x = 2, your *global* would be simply x = 2, which is the same as saying window.x = 2;

Comment: Okay I get that but how is `this` in the global namespace of `window`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Everything is public in Javascript, there is no access control like in an object oriented language. The "private" variables in the example are only protected by the fact that there is no way to describe how to access them from outside the function.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey ya, you're combining two different topics. I'm talking about "function scope" in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

`var` will declare a variable local to the function. I think you meant to assign it to `this.returnValue`:

```
function addThis() {
    this.value1 = 1;
    this.value2 = 2;

    this.returnValue = function () {
        return (this.value1 + this.value2);
    };
}

// Instantiate object and write response
var simpleObject = new addThis();
document.write(simpleObject.returnValue());
```